# Whenever I tap on Textfield it shows me a White Container. How to remove that issue in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Whenever I tap on Textfield it shows me this white container. How do I remove that?

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code for this page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap everything in a `SingleChildScrollView` and set the `reverse` to `true`.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
   reverse: true,
   child: Container(),
);
```

Comment: After adding flutter new version of 2.0.0 its not showing the option of resizeToAvoidBottomPadding in scaffold.

Comment: I've updated, next time specify the version in your question and provide your code, thank you